# Removing a Class oninput Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have successfully created a javascript validation using bootstrap which add class `is-invalid` when the field is null, however I want to remove that class during `oninput` event.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" oninput="rmv()">
<input type="text" name="emp_fn" id="emp_fn" oninput="rmv()">
```

on JS:

```
function rmv(){
document.getElementsByClassName("is-invalid");
error.oninput = function(){
error.classList.remove('is-invalid');
}}
```

I have simplified the above code, please note that I have a lot of text boxes with validation `is-invalid` class and I only want to remove that class on the active textbox im typing with. Thank you. (newbiee)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements. You don’t seem to use the return value here.

Comment: Hi, I understand. It works perfectly when you return a specific value or name of the input. However I dont want to create a long repititive code, because I have a lot of textboxes and fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `oninput(this)` and remove the class `in-invalid`.

You do not need `getElementsByClassName` here to remove the class from your input when you type something.

> In the `rmv()` function `this` refers to the elements we have typed in something

This will work with `multiple` elements as soon as you start `typing` in the input the `is-invalid` class will be `removed`

**Edit:** You can also check if the input has a value then `remove` class OR `add` class again.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function rmv(event) {
   event.value ? event.classList.remove('is-invalid') : event.classList.add('is-invalid'); //add or remove class input has a value
}
```

```css
.is-invalid {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="emp_id" class="is-invalid" id="emp_id" oninput="rmv(this)">
<input type="text" name="emp_fn" class="is-invalid"  id="emp_fn" oninput="rmv(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```js
function rmv(input){
    if(input.value) {
      input.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    } else {
      input.classList.add('is-invalid');
    }
}
```

```css
.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background-color: #ff000011;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="is-invalid" name="emp_id" id="emp_id" oninput="rmv(this)">
<input type="text" class="is-invalid" name="emp_fn" id="emp_fn" oninput="rmv(this)">
```